# How to pass data between two pages in a windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have an app in javascript and html, i want send data to other page, to access the page i use WinJS.Navigation.navigate.

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate('../pages/Resumen/Resumen.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put parameter like this:

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate('../pages/Resumen/Resumen.html', value);
```

And get this parameter in target page:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
    //your value is in options parametr 
}
```